# How can I dotnetnuke in another application

Tags: asp.net, dotnetnuke

I have developed an application that would allow users to login to complete different tasks. However, I'm using an existing dnn database for the login; I've recognzied that the portal stores the password using encryption but I can't get source code used to encrypt the password inorder for the password entered by the user to match of that in the dnn database. How can I get around this? The DNN version is 04.09.05

Update

```
 try
    {
        //validate username/password combination
        DotNetNuke.Entities.Users.UserInfo myUser = new DotNetNuke.Entities.Users.UserInfo();
        DotNetNuke.Security.Membership.UserLoginStatus userLoginStatus = new DotNetNuke.Security.Membership.UserLoginStatus();
       myUser = DotNetNuke.Entities.Users.UserController.ValidateUser(myPortal, myUsername, myPassword, "", "", "", ref userLoginStatus);

        if (userLoginStatus == DotNetNuke.Security.Membership.UserLoginStatus.LOGIN_SUCCESS ||
        userLoginStatus == DotNetNuke.Security.Membership.UserLoginStatus.LOGIN_SUPERUSER)
        {
            //login the user ...
            DotNetNuke.Entities.Users.UserController.UserLogin(PortalId, myUser, "", "", true);
            Response.Redirect("~/Home/Welcome.aspx");
        }
        else
        {
            lblError.Text = "Invalid Username or Password";
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        lblError.Text = "Error!! " + ex.Message.ToString();
    }


}
```

Comment: I highly doubt DNN stores the password encrypted, and I've never used DNN. There's a difference between encrypted and hashed. Encrypting implies that the data can be decrypted. Encryption is two way. Hashing is one way: once something is hashed, it's not mathematically possible to reverse the process. We stored passwords hashed, not encrypted. We then compare hashed forms of the passwords when authenticating a user.

Comment: It might be time to upgrade. DNN 5 was released back in 2008! Older versions have known vulnerabilities. But the DNN login is build on the aspnet Forms Authentication, so you might be able to bypass the DNN authentication and validate directly against the framework. But I don't know if that is even possible, with or without DNN.

Comment: @mason; i'm aware of that information but at the moment that's what is been used.

Comment: @VDWWD; so there's no way to create a function that allows the user to login

Comment: Saying "don't know if something is possible" is different from saying "it's not possible". You'll have to investigate it. Knowing that it's built on the old forms auth framework should inform you about what to research.

Comment: @VDWWD; is just the tables i'm using from the dnn database an match what was entered by the user against the database. Isn't that possible

Comment: Like I said, I don't know unfortunately. But the passwords are stored encrypted with a hash and an Application ID. So there are several problems you need to solve.

Comment: @VDWWD What are those problems? besides that the password is encrypted rather than hashed. Can you explain further please?

Comment: Figuring out how to combine all those to check the username/password combo in another application.

Comment: @VDWWD that's a tricky one when i don't know function used to encrypt the password. isn't one set way the password is encrypted in dnn

Answer (score 0):

The source code for DNN 4.9.5 is available, you have a few options.

1. You could deploy a service to the 4.9.5 installation exposing login as an API for the external applications.  This would allow you tou se the DNN 4.x API's as intended and would not require custom circumvention, this would also work well in the future for you.
2. You could review the source and pull the login code from `UserController.ValidateUser` and re-implement this in your code.  The password salting and encryption process is that of the standard ASP.NET Membership.  Your biggest concern here is that you will need to keep the Machine Key values the same between DNN & the other application

Also, just because it was mentioned in comments.  I STRONGLY recommend upgrading if this is public.  There are more than 30 security vulnerabilities that apply to your current DNN Version.

Comment: it is not public. Where do I find this login code UserController.ValidateUser

Comment: All source is public and on GitHub.com

Comment: can you give a sample code to use. i've tried a number of solutions but none seems to work

Comment: i've updated the question with what I now have; but giving an error message CS0103: The name 'myPortal' does not exist in the current context. where do I save myportal in a different class

Comment: You must run the DNN COde, as is, inside of the DNN Context.  You would need to extract this to a different location or otherwise.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't have an example to this, as it really isn't recommended practice so I don't have it in my repository